# ASP.NET:Enable Delete facility in Entity Data Source

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, entity-framework-4.1

I have created a `Grid View` that use `Entity Data Source` as its `Data Source`.

I used `Command Text` in my `Entity Data Source` because i have to join two tables for displaying data in grid view.

But `Command Text` cannot be set if `Enable Delete, Enable Insert, or Enable Update` is enabled. so i disabled them.

But i need to use delete facility. How cloud i do that ?

Comment: since the grid contains joined tables what would the delete actually delete?

Comment: @Pawel  ohh. that's true. but is there any way to do this ? (by supplying a key or any other way.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot set primary key in database